# How to Automatically Link Frameworks or Libraries

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, templates

I am building an app, that I want to create a template out of. In that app I manually create links to several Frameworks/Libraries.

Is there a way to automatically create those links?

Thank you,

-- Eric

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to add those links. You just need to add them one by one. If you need to import some header files in almost all your source code file, you can consider to add them in your *-Prefix.pch file.